# Create a menu link to a particular node type in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

So, I have created a content type "Vehicle". Basically I create a submission form that allows users to submit vehicle information. So, I want to create a menu link called "vehicle" and it brings me to the page where all the "Vehicle" posts are listed. Is there anyway to do this?

I understand that this is the job of [view module](http://drupal.org/project/views). But when I run the instructions [on this site](http://drupal.org/node/244281), it doesn't seem to fit well with with [drupal 6](http://drupal.org/drupal-6.0) and the [view module](http://drupal.org/project/views) I downloaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use node view module and you can view all posts